# PHP mail is sending to local e-mail server

Tags: php, email, dns

I have just published the website of one of my customers but am facing issues with getting the contact form to work properly.

Their website is hosted on server A (uses DirectAdmin).
Their e-mail is hosted at an external company ('server B') using other MX entries in their DNS.

The contact form is supposed to send all e-mails to info@domainname.com at server B. The e-mails however, are not being sent to the external e-mail box at server B, but they're sent to the local e-mail box on server A.

Looks like the server/PHP is thinking that the e-mail is local anyway because the e-mail domain matches the domain in DirectAdmin, right?

Is there any way I can avoid this? Like making the PHP e-mail future know that the e-mail is not local? Or is the only option to use SMTP?

Comment: well, there could be other reasons, for example, the domain name is created in the local bind or whatever the dns resolver is (this if you have own dns service hosted) or there is some email account created on `server A` which matches the same name. The solution would be, to remove any references on `server A` to the domain and/or email accounts. I don't think that a simple webhost could cause problems

Comment: I've had this exact problem with a hosting service. Local DNS server was configured for my domain but I was hosting DNS elsewhere. It only got solved when Support manually removed my domain from their DNS.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that DirectAdmin has a function to uncheck local e-mail servers and change MX records used. Perhaps that'll do the job, sounds like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest SMTP is the way to go, i have found i get much better results with it anyway in terms of spam filters etc.

My preferred solution is to use: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

i have built a helper function to make it easier for me to implement it

**Function - file name: smtp.function **

```
<?php


//SMTP controller FUNCTION for PHPMailer script
//source of script: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
require ('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

function SMTP
($to, $subject,$html, $text='')
{

    //UPDATE SETTINGS TO MATCH PROJECT SETTINGS
    $settings = array('host'=>'XXXXXX','username'=>'XXXXXX','password'=>'XXXXXX','fromEmail'=>'XXXXXX', 'fromName'=>'XXXXXX','replyEmail'=>'XXXXXX', 'replyName'=>'XXXXXX');


        $mail = new PHPMailer;

            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = $settings['host'];  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = $settings['username'];                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = $settings['password'];                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
            $mail->From = $settings['fromEmail'];
            $mail->FromName = $settings['fromName'];
            //$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
            $mail->addAddress($to);               // Name is optional
            $mail->addReplyTo($settings['replyEmail'], $settings['replyName']);
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body    = $html;
            $mail->AltBody = $text;



//WHAT TO DO IF EMAIL SENDS OR NOT
            if(!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } 

            else {
                echo 'Message has been sent';
            }



}


?>
```

**Calling it in PHP**

```
<?php
require('smtp.function');

SMTP('to@domain.com',' This is a test of the SMTP class by Alex','<strong>This test</strong> is <a href="http://www.google.co.uk">HTML CODE</a>');




?>
```

Comment: I just got it to work by changing the MX records on server A.

I however will definitely look into this. This is obviously a much better way in terms of spam filters for sure. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If DNS records are messed up this solution will not work at all unless you find a third-party email provider—"switch to SMTP" is a most confusing advice.